# where is the googleapis (Google APIs Node.js Client) gmail documentation?

Tags: node.js, documentation, gmail-api

Enter that url: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/ and then search for "gmail" to finally enter: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/gmail/index.html and find that there is practically nothing related to gmail

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? 

[https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/discovery/gmail-v1.json](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/discovery/gmail-v1.json)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly